# Store objects at "request scope" in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scope, httprequest

I would like to store some information at the "request scope" when using google app engine (python). What I mean by this is that I would like to initialize some information when a request is first received, and then be able to access it from anywhere for the life of the request (and only from that request).

An example of this would be if I saved the current user's name at request scope after they were authenticated.

How would I go about doing this sort of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using? Probably you want middleware.

Comment: Then just set the value of a local variable at the beginning of your CGI script. (If you don't define a function named `main()`, the whole thing will be thrown out after each request.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern used in app engine itself seems to be `threading.local` which you can grep for in the SDK code. Making os.environ request local is done like that in `runtime/request_environment.py` for example.

A rough example:

```
import threading

class _State(threading.local):
    """State keeps track of request info"""
    user = None

_state = _State()
```

From elsewhere you could authenticate early on in handler code.

```
from state import _state
if authentication_passed:
    _state.user = user
```

and provide convenience that can be used in other parts of your code

```
from state import _state
def get_authenticated_user():
    user = _state.user
    if not user:
        raise AuthenticationError()
    return user
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:-

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  #A function which is useful in order to determine whether user is logged in
  def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
    #Do the authentication
    self.username = username


class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
 def get(self):
   print self.username
```

Now if you inherit BaseHandler class  all the request will first go through the initialize method of BaseHandler class and since in the BaseHandler class you are setting the username
 and MainHandler inherits form BaseHandler you will have the self.username defined and all the request wil go through initialize method.

Comment: OP says he's not using webapp2 framework, so a solution that involves subclassing `webapp2.RequestHandler` probably isn't going to work.

Comment: He said hes using google app engine..By default google app engine comes with webapp2 module.So i suggested him the following answer